# RxJava io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Must be called from main thread of fragment host

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

I am a little confused about thread handling in RxJava.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    clickObservable = RxView.clicks(button);
    vpPager = findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

    //debouncebale button.
    disposable = clickObservable
            .debounce(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Object o) throws Exception {
                    //This prints main thread.
                    Log.d(TAG, " o " + o + " thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    vpPager.setCurrentItem(vpPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
                }
            });

    pageChangedObservable = RxViewPager.pageSelections(vpPager);
    pageChangedObservable
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .delay(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(final Integer integer) throws Exception {
                    //This prints Thread RxComputationThreadPool-1
                    Log.d(TAG, "Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    vpPager.setCurrentItem(integer  + 1, true);
                }
            });



}
```

The first Log statement prints main thread, the second Log statement prints RxComputationThreadPool-1. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

be mindful that some operators operate on designated default `Scheduler`s, particularly operators (such as `delay` in this case) that have to do with time offsets. otherwise, if no `Scheduler` were specified, they would block the main thread as they wait before generating their next emission.

if you check the [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#delay-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), you'll see that `delay` operates on the computation `Scheduler` by default.

also, for those operators that have default `Scheduler`s, there is usually an overloaded variant that allows you to specify your desired `Scheduler`.

Comment: I am not really sure how this answers my question at all ?

Comment: the question i answered was "The first Log statement prints main thread, the second Log statement prints RxComputationThreadPool-1. I am not sure why." i explained that some operators use default `Scheduler`s, which is why you're seeing the logging from a different thread. what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually delay() uses Schedulers.computation() by default if you don't provide a Scheduler.

In your 2nd case, you should use

.delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

if you want to observe result in the main thread. Or move the

.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

after .delay();

You can find this when you go to the definition of .delay() method.

/**
     * Returns an Observable that emits the items emitted by the source ObservableSource shifted forward in time by a
     * specified delay. Error notifications from the source ObservableSource are not delayed.
     *

**Scheduler:**

*  This version of {@code delay} operates by default on the {@code computation} {@link Scheduler}
Hope I answer your question.